# Regex: whitelist of characters + maxmim length + no dot at the end

Tags: regex

I do not know why i'm struggling with this simple regex, but I am :)

I need a regex to match a string:

- with the allowed characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`
- that contains 1 to 48 characters
- that can have dots, but not at the end of the string

Tried a bunch of regexes, but there's always something that slips through the matching. I ended up with

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,48})([^.])$
```

For some reason, `test$` for example is accepted as valid. `test$$` isn't.

Can someone help me get on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind if it is supported by your regex engine:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,48}(?<!\.)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA5vO9)**

If your regex engine doesn't support negative lookbehinds, but supports negative lookaheads, then the following will work for you:

```
^(?!.*\.$)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,48}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS4jD7)**

Comment: Thanks Ulugbek! This seems to get passed all my checks, both of them.

Answer (score 1):

`[^.]` ends your regex and will match any character except a dot, so you're actually checking for a string 2 to 49 character long, the last one being anything but `.`.

To check your criteria you can use instead:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,47}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$
```

This one is taking into account that the last character class is "eating up" a character.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Robin, that regex also seems to work.